# Multiple setup projects for different languages and brand names

Tags: visual-studio, resources, localization, installation

I need to rebrand my application, that means create another application resource file with different strings, slash screen and icons.

My application is also localized for a second language, i have another resource file with all application string which is translated, that creates me additional, satellite dll.

I need to build 4 setup project 2 for each language and 2 for each brand name.

What will the elegant solution for this? Is there any way to create additional application resource file same way I did with language translation and how I include a satellite (resource in a second language dll)  in my setup project and not including resources in the original, neutral language.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that those branding resources are not in setup project, but in main project, and that main project is C++.

In C++ you can have several .rc files in a project. This is most likely true for C# resources too. Move all branding material to second resource file. Create another project, shallow in nature, that references all files (including .rc) from original, but uses its own versions of branding files. Apart from strings, icons, and images maybe you will have some dialogs copied and branded as well. Make sure they all have resource identifiers in sync.

Creating another project can be done by just copying original project and fiddling with paths in text editor. Just make sure you change the project GUID, so that two project can coexist in the same solution.

Comment: Is there any other solution except than coping the application project? I already have two resource files in my application project, how i can create a two setup project for each resource file?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to have one application project but two setup projects with different application in each. This is impossible. You can have the same application in each, but which behaves differently based on some registry entry.